# Why developer used SELECT 1 IN PROCEDURE

Tags: t-sql

Why developer used SELECT 1 IN PROCEDURE? Is this something intended?

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[AddCallerInVoiceComplaint]

    @COMPNO VARCHAR(20),

    @CALLERNAME VARCHAR(50),

    @CALLERMOBILENO BIGINT,

    @EMAILID varchar(50)

    AS BEGIN

    UPDATE VoiceComplaints 
    SET CallerName2 = @CALLERNAME, 
        CallerMobileNo2 = @CALLERMOBILENO, 
        CallerEmailid2 = @EMAILID     
    WHERE ComplaintNumber = @COMPNO

    SELECT 1

    END
```

Comment: Why don't you ask that developer?

Comment: Often used to show that a proc is successful

Comment: Probably as an "answer back" from stored procedure that it was successfully completed, he could also use "Rows affected" as answer, lots of ways to do that ... or he just simply forgot to remove it ... or use that 1 value for something in further of code, we can just keep guessing and i'm running out of inspiration this morning

Comment: In short - its a crude hack. Stored procedures might be called from other procedures, or from external code. Sometimes, this code expects that such a call return a result set (i.e. result of a `SELECT` query). In the stored procedure above, the UPDATE statement does not return a result set. To work around this, the developer has used `SELECT 1` to fake the caller into thinking that is the result set.

Comment: BUT GENERALLY  WHY WE  USE SELECT 1 IN SQL

Comment: @Anup - its a simple (probably the simplest) SQL statement that can be run, and doesn't depend on any tables to be present since `1` is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UPDATE` statement doesn't generate a rowset as output, so there could be something looking for the 1 returned as a "update occured with no errors" signal